# duplicate records when destroying associated models during update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hihi,
Im on ROR 4.1.6.rc1
I have a model as described below

```
class MainSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... 
  has_many :citizenship_requirements, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :citizenship_requirements, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: lambda { |attribute| attribute['citizenship_id'] == "0" }
  ...
end
```

Was trying to update the citizenship_requirements associations base on checkboxes, whereby those associated models that are not checked will be deleted

MainSlotsController:

```
def edit
  @company = Company.find(@company_id)
  @main_slot = MainSlot.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def update
  binding.pry
  main_slot = MainSlot.find(params[:id])
  if main_slot.update_attributes(main_slot_params)
    flash[:success] = "Job is successfully updated!"
    redirect_to main_slots_path
  else
    flash[:success] = "There was an error updating the job. Please try again."
    redirect_to main_slots_path
  end
end

private
  def main_slot_params
    params.require(:main_slot).permit(
      :id, 
      ..., 
      company_job_title_attributes: [:id, :job_title_name, :job_function_id, :company_id], 
      citizenship_requirements_attributes: [:id, :citizenship_id, :_destroy, :cr_id],
      ... )
  end
```

At the line where binding.pry is, my params is as such (cr_id is the primary key)

```
"main_slot"=>
{
  ...
  "citizenship_requirements_attributes"=>
   [{"citizenship_id"=>"1", "cr_id"=>"6033", "_destroy"=>"true"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"2", "cr_id"=>"6034", "_destroy"=>"true"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"3", "cr_id"=>"6035", "_destroy"=>"true"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"4", "cr_id"=>"6036", "_destroy"=>"true"}],
...
}
```

However upon update, nothing happen. The record still remains with the same cr_id etc.

How should I go about deleting nested models upon update?

In addition, for a params as such

```
"main_slot"=>
{
  ...
  "citizenship_requirements_attributes"=>
   [{"citizenship_id"=>"1", "cr_id"=>"6033", "_destroy"=>"false"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"2", "cr_id"=>"6034", "_destroy"=>"false"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"3", "cr_id"=>"6035", "_destroy"=>"true"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"4", "cr_id"=>"6036", "_destroy"=>"true"}],
...
}
```

I get the error "Duplicate entry '6033' for key 'PRIMARY'". Rails docs is saying "If the hash contains an id key that matches an already associated record, the matching record will be modified:" for updating nested models in this link: "http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html"

Not sure what I am doing wrong :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say you have a problem with missing `id` for each nested citizenship_requirement. Update is performed on nested associations only if `id` of such nested object is present. Now it should create another citizenship_requirements for each element with `"_destroy"=>"false"`, because of missing `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @blelump, you're right. It worked when my params was made as such:

```
"main_slot"=>
{
  ...
  "citizenship_requirements_attributes"=>
   [{"citizenship_id"=>"1", "id"=>"6033", "_destroy"=>"false"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"2", "id"=>"6034", "_destroy"=>"false"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"3", "id"=>"6035", "_destroy"=>"true"},
    {"citizenship_id"=>"4", "id"=>"6036", "_destroy"=>"true"}],
  ...
}
```

It looks for 'id' and 'id' only like what u said. Kudos